# Javascript Get active menu item data-option-value and put it into a VAR

Tags: javascript, class, attributes, jquery-isotope, var

```
    <div class="option-combo department">  
   <span class="label_menu">Department:</span>  
   <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">  
    <li class="department-button"><a href="#" id="all" data-option-value=":not(.comm)">All</a></li> 
    <li class="department-button"><a href="#" id="sales" data-option-value=".sales:not(.comm)">Sales</a></li>   
    <li class="department-button"><a href="#" id="market" data-option-value=".market:not(.comm)">Marketing</a></li>  
    <li class="department-button"><a href="#" id="training" data-option-value=".training:not(.comm)">Training</a></li> 
    <li class="department-button"><a href="#" data-option-value=".comm">Communications</a></li> 
   </ul> 
   </div>
```

I want to get the active list items attribute, data-option-value, and add it to the commiunication data-option-value dynamically

I am using isotope

Answer (score 0):

Try this to filter out the other classes and just show the specific communications for each department

```
<li class="department-button"><a href="#" data-option-value=".market.comm">Communications</a></li>
```

Comment: That tottally helps me with a seperate issue, but I still need to pull the active department to filter them with one button.

Comment: Maybe you could create a dropdown with each specific department for communications or see this

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html#content

Comment: That would be a work around but I would still like to learn how to pull this into a js variable